# Java Version in user profile without privileges

Tags: java, cmd

I need some help with **cmd and java version**. When I type into cmd **java -version with user profile without privileges**,the output is diferent if i typed into cmd **java -version with administrator profile**. I updated Java...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like your user and administrator account have different PATH-Variables pointing to different java.exe-files...